# Webbrowser is not disposing itself

Tags: wpf, browser, dispose

I am creating a WPF application. I created a usercontrol and put a back button and webbrowser. The webbrowser is for showing some Flash objects and works without a problem. However, when I click back, the program returns to previous user control but I can still hear some sound coming from webbrowser. Here is my method:

```
void btnClose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Content contentPage = new Content();
    webBrowser1.Dispose();
    this.Content = contentPage;
}
```

How can I dispose webbrowser? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of calling Dispose, you should reset the [WebBrowser.Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.source.aspx) property:

```
webBrowser1.Source = null;
```