# WPF MVVM WebBrowser dispose

Tags: wpf, pdf, webbrowser-control, dispose

I am having WebBrowser in my WPF application. I use it for viewing pdf files. But after 50 files are viewed the app throws an exception. So we decided to dispose webbrowser before opening next pdf.
The thing is I do not know how exactly to do that. When I dispose webbrowser it is unbinded and no pdf is viewed anymore. It makes sence, but how to do that correctly?
Here is my code:

```
public static void BindableSourcePropertyChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowser browser = o as WebBrowser;
        if (browser != null)
        {
            try
            {
                browser.Dispose();
                browser = null;
                browser = new WebBrowser();
            }
            catch
            {
            }

            string uri = e.NewValue as string;


            try
            {
                if (uri != null)
                {
                    browser.Navigate(new Uri(uri, UriKind.Absolute));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                ExceptionPolicy.HandleException(exception, ExceptionPolicies.General);
            }
        }
    }
```

And xaml part:

```
<WebBrowser Grid.Row="0" Behaviour:WebBrowserBehaviour.BindableSource="{Binding WebBrowserData}" 
                LoadCompleted="WebBrowser_LoadCompleted" />
```

Comment: Try to set the Source property to null as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162240/webbrowser-is-not-disposing-itself

Comment: Thanks,but this is not the correct solution. It does not frees the resources

Comment: Check the DisposeWebBrowser() method here then: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/368755dd-0047-4a88-9951-ba0539266410/wpf-webbrowser-is-not-disposed-properly?forum=wpf

Comment: Ok,but I need to have browser available again. When I call dispose, then dependencyObject is not available anymore. I actually have datagrid with many rows and there is webbrowser below. After clicking on the row of the datagrid the pdf file is viewed in the browser. So I need to clear memory or so and show another file.

Comment: Once you dispose an object you cannot (or at least you are not supposed to) ever use it again. So once you have disposed a WebBrowser you have to create a new instance of the WebBrowser control. If you don't want to do this it makes no sense to dispose it in the first place.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know if by chance there isn't any possible magic to renew it somehow. When you do that with winform app, you just make new webbrowser to webbrowser control and everything works well. I just wanted to ask before I change the control not to being MVVM, but code behind. Maybe it is gonna works better ...

Answer (score 0):

Basically the problem sounds like you have a memory leak. To help identify it you should use software designed that that purpose. RedAnt has a nice library that I believe has a free trial you can use to help determine what the exact cause of the issue is.

To dispose after loading you can do what is suggested here:
[How to dispose of a web browser control after show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784973/when-how-to-dispose-of-a-web-browser-control-after-show-print-preview-dialog)

But I would suggest you prove that is the problem first by watching the memory or using a tool designed to help detect leaks.